# OpenMPI built from source not working on a raspberry pi + mac cluster

Tags: macos, networking, openmpi, raspberry-pi4, mpi4py

I am trying to use macbook m1 as the master in a cluster of 4 raspberry pies (workers, connected to each other with a switch which is connected to my home router to which the mac is connected via wifi). I built OpenMPI (4.1.5) from source for both raspberry pi 4 and the macbook  and have configured everything correctly with hosts and hostnames and saved public keys in each raspberry for direct login from the master.

However, when I run

```
mpiexec -machinefile machinefile -n 5 python mpi_run.py
```

machinefile

```
MacBook-Air.attlocal.net
rpi1
rpi2
rpi3
rpi4
```

mpi_run.py file

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import sys

size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

sys.stdout.write(
    "Hello, World! I am process %d of %d on %s.\n"
    % (rank, size, name))
```

a test example it just doesn't output anything. The working animation in the top right of the terminal runs for a few seconds and then nothing happens, no output or error.
The mpiexec does run individually on each machine.